# php - foreach - get the specific data by key name

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

how to get specific data by key name from the following foreach code.

```
    <?php
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    echo $key." ".$val."<br/>";
    ?>
```

array is look like this want to get value of specific key.

```
   {"name":"bedroom","rent":"sale","props":"","leases":""}
```

i have tried following code but doesn't work

```
echo "checking key sep. ".$key[rent];
```

if possible i can access by key name like name or rent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is in JSON , you need to decode it first by using `json_decode()`

Something like this...

```
$yourJSON = '{"name":"bedroom","rent":"sale","props":"","leases":""}';
$yourarray = json_decode($yourJSON,1);
```

You can then loop the `$yourarray` using the `foreach` construct like this.

```
foreach($yourarray as $key=>$val)
{
echo $key." ".$val."<br/>";
}
```

For retrieving a specific key from it..

```
   echo $yourarray['rent']; //"prints" sale
```