# Access specific key in foreach array

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I need to access a specific custom header to determine what content to serve. I can get the headers and output an array like this:

```
<?php
    headers = apache_request_headers();
    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
     }
?>
```

It outputs all headers, the one I need to access is: X-Language-Locale: it-IT

I need to parse all of the array for "X-Language-Locale" and run an if else statement to determine what content to serve. How do I do this?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php example 6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php - foreach - get the specific data by key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212740/php-foreach-get-the-specific-data-by-key-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it without the foreach loop.

```
if($headers['X-Language-Locale'] == 'it-IT') {
    echo 'ok';
}else {
    echo 'not italian';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use indexed access, since you have a constant key that you want to look for. Most objects that have key-value pairs can also be accessed using the [key as an index](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php).

```php
<?php
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $lang_locale = $headers["X-language-locale"];
    if ($lang_locale == "it-IT") {
        // DO SOMETHING
    } else {
        // DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
?>
```

Comment: Normal situation this would work perfectly. Due to the translation proxy we're using the content gets a little mangled. Thank you.